# How do I set text-overflow to ellipsis in CSS grid layout?

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a grid layout like the one in `header` below. There is a text in the div whose width is `1fr`. I want the text inside that div to be truncated when it is too long. Adding `text-overflow` as `ellpsis` is not working. Any idea how to do it?

It has to be grid and there is no way I can change that.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  display: flex;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}

content {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: red;
}

header {
  background-color: limegreen;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0fr 1fr 0fr;
}

header div {
  border: 1px solid orange;
}

.long {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <div>Left</div>
    <div class="long">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
    <div>Right</div>
  </header>
  <content>
  </content>
</div>
```

Comment: add this property to .long { white-space: nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:elipses;} hope this works here is a reference link https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/

Answer (score 31, accepted):

change .long css to below

```
.long {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

the reason why you need to add white-space and overflow is below:

1. you need `white-space: nowrap` to tell browsers to not wrap when text length exceed containing block width, `white-space` properties default value is normal, which indicates it can wrap, so it won't exist the situation where text overflow;
2. `overflow` default value is visible, when text exceeds containing block, it just display, so there is no need to overflow text to display, only if you set `overflow` to `hidden`. Then, when text can not fully displayed, it will use `text-overflow` property.

Comment: This one doesnt work for me. When using FR-units in a gridlayout it seems it just expands the box. Or am I doing something wrong? Usually the above code works, but first time Ive tried in a grid layout.

Comment: Isn't this basically the same answer Ehsan gave?

Comment: This doesn't answer the original question where the text is inside a container that is an element of a css grid.

Comment: This doesn't fully answer the question of truncating text in the context of CSS Grid Layout. When I added `max-width: 100%`, it started working for me.

Comment: @MortenHjort To make it work in a grid layout, wrap `.long` in a `div` which becomes the column with FR-unit `1fr` and set `overflow: hidden` on this new `div`.

Comment: @MortenHjort add a `minmax` in your grid definition, like so: `grid-template-columns: minmax(0, 1fr)`. See https://css-tricks.com/preventing-a-grid-blowout/

Comment: @e18r - perfect, that worked like a charm!

Comment: @MortenHjort add `min-width: 0` to your  grid items, that should work.

Comment: Just as @e18r said, wrapping the `fr` value in `minmax` worked.

Comment: I agree with @MortenHjort
In my case removing display: flex from the child in grid works for me with the above solution.

Comment: @e18r You should write a solution, because only this works!! Been looking for hours.

Comment: @e-motiv please feel free to write it yourself. I wrote this 3.5 years ago, so I don't remember a thing. It'd be irresponsible to write anything at this point. You, on the other hand, have it fresh in your mind and your technique is up-to-date.

Answer (score 4):

Add `overflow: hidden` and `white-space: nowrap` when you used `text-overflow`

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  display: flex;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}

content {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: red;
}

header {
  background-color: limegreen;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0fr 1fr 0fr;
}

header div {
  border: 1px solid orange;
}

.long {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <div>Left</div>
    <div class="long">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
    <div>Right</div>
  </header>
  <content>
  </content>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the trick that works in Chrome, but FireFox (currently v57) seems to not handle truncation very well, especially with CSS grid. The `.long` element just pushes the `.container` wider.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) when use `text-overflow: ellipsis;` must use `overflow: hidden;` too.
>
> 2)`white-space: nowrap;` Does not allow text break in new line.

**So, Change Like This :**

```
.long {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;/*/<------------new/*/
  white-space: nowrap;/*/<---------new/*/
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Define a height, set `white-space` to `nowrap` and `overflow: hidden`

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  display: flex;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}

content {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: red;
}

header {
  background-color: limegreen;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0fr 1fr 0fr;
}

header div {
  border: 1px solid orange;
}

.long {
  height: 20px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <div>Left</div>
    <div class="long">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
    <div>Right</div>
  </header>
  <content>
  </content>
</div>
```

Comment: To have ellipsis text inside a grid item you need `min-height: 0`on the container. Check https://dev.to/timhecker/grid-cell-issue-with-white-space-nowrap--text-overflow-ellipsis-52g6

Comment: It works in the code snippet... Not sure why I've got -1 on my comment when people who gave exactly the same answer after me have got upvoted answers...

Comment: @darkyndy You meant `min-width: 0`. Good solution though. It's the only solution that actually solves the issue without having to specify a fixed width in pixels, which would utterly defeat the purpose of CSS Grid!